# simple sample for google analytics eventtracker in android

Tags: java, android, google-analytics-api

I am trying to simply send an event from my app to Google Analytics.
- I have an account with my UA- ID. 
- Google Play Services Revision 17 is installed and all configuration done.

I searched in Google for samples how to do this and found a lot of samples, but none of them worked for me. I get syntax errors not runtime errors. I also do not know which version of Google Analytics (v4?) I have installed, because this would be relevant for the samples I find in the net.

Questions:
- How do I find out which version is installed ?
- Is there any simple sample to only send an event.

I my code here I started so far:

```
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-1";
    private Tracker googleanalyticstracker;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        googleanalyticstracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio then you can just open up your Android SDK Manager and when you scroll all the way to the bottom it will show you the "Extra" items you have installed and Google Analytics is listed there with the version that is installed as well. You have everything setup for the google tracker you just need to send the hit to Google using the "send" command for your tracker. This is what I have for sending hits (I have a couple custom items that are sent as well but it should give you an idea of what's needed).

```
//setup tracker
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
        //analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker(trackerID);
        tracker.setScreenName(screenName);
        //send information to Google Analytics
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder()
                .setCustomDimension(1, programName)
                .setCustomDimension(2, billingLevel)
                .setCustomDimension(3, repRole)
                .setCustomDimension(4, repID)
                .setCustomDimension(5, repFullName)
                .build());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats a simple sample that helped me. No Syntax Error and no Runtime Error. Saw my first hit in Google Analytics. Do you know which Google Analytics SDK Version you have installed ?

Comment: I'm currently using version 3, since it's the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Google Analytics is V3.

Refer this link : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

Comment: I found that too. This doesn't help because it throws syntax errors. Howto findout which GoogleAnalytics Version I have ?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Google Analytics V3

> simple sample to only send an event.

```
private Tracker mTracker;  
...
...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
}          
.....
.....

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "SCREEN NAME"); // assign a name for the screen
    mTracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build()); // send the event to analytics id
}
```

This is a sample code used within a "fragment"

To download the analytics jar file for V3 use this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/)